# SQL Matching Make and Model by year range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set in the following format:

```
Name 
CustomerNumber
ModelYear
Manufacturer
Model
SerialNumber
```

I want to be able to find the customers that have 3 or more of the same manufacturer and model within the last four model years. Thank you in advance for any help that you could provide. The data set has aprox 600k rows.

Comment: Question not complete

Comment: Add sample table data, and it's expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: The DBMS is MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT 
CustomerOrders.CustomerNumber, 
Count(*) AS Orders, 
CustomerOrders.Manufacturer, 
CustomerOrders.Model

FROM CustomerOrders
WHERE CustomerOrders.ModelYear>=Year(Date())-4)
GROUP BY 
CustomerOrders.CustomerNumber, 
CustomerOrders.Manufacturer, 
CustomerOrders.Model
HAVING Count(*) >= 3;
```